# Cucumber Tests Framework

Tags: ruby, maven, automation, cucumber, automated-tests

We are looking at cucumber for our automation test framework because everyone including business people can understand it.

We use Angualr JS frontend and Java REST backend. Our team that is going to write the step definitions likes Ruby so we want to stick with Ruby for that.

Also we would like to use Maven to tie this process into our build process.

Will cucumber be a good fit given that story above ?

Comment: Cucumber also offers JavaScript and Java/JVM versions which you might also consider to be used with Angular front end / Java backend. We use cucumber-jvm for both front end tests (Angular apps) and to test endpoints/API's

Answer (score 1):

Hui Peztherez, from my prospective cucumber is a great choice, using it with the same architecture expect for Angular.

We are using Maven too, and it's so useful to orchestrate them with Jenkins, using maven to run the tags..

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @smoke"
```

ref: https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm

Also Jenkins have several plugin to report the Cucumber Analysis, so useful for testers, and in the end, we are now working about the HPQ server integration with a plugin called Bumblebee (this part is still under development for both sides, our and bumblebee)

Another good choice is Ruby, you can take the step definition so easily defined with Ruby...

We also have a integration with Selenium for the front end side, and it works as well...

So go further!

Answer (score 1):

We are using Cucumber in Java with gradle in past, It was in Maven and It works fine. We have framework for UI and API, In UI we used WebDriver to write step definition and In API, We used RestAssured to write step definition. You can do same thing in Java what you can do in Ruby.

*Maven for Java Cucumber* :
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java/1.2.4 - *Please add other dependency as per requirement.*

*Jenkin Plugin :* https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin

**Will cucumber be a good fit given that story above ?**
 - Yes It is good fit. I will request you to show POC(Proof of concept) to management. I had experience in past that management have no clue about BDD and they have very hard to time to understand coverage. We did very deep dive to provide all information to them. It is very important to answer following question to management

- BDD report is providing accurate test converage idea to management ?
- Everyone in team is able to write feature file and able to provide same quality of feature file
- Feature file and BDD report will be starting tool for check test converage

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that Cucumber is a [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) framework that can be used on top of a browser automation framework like Selenium WebDriver/Watir/Protractor they are two distinct things. Most of them implements Selenium WebDriver's protocol.

My only concern is for you using Maven in that project setup, I know that you can run ruby code in a JVM by using [JRuby](http://jruby.org/). But I'm not sure which plugin you'd use to trigger that from Maven.

Comment: Note that Cucumber (as a BDD tool) describes the behavior of the system, not the implementation. So you don't *need* to use Selenium and go through the UI. You could (and probably should!) automate at other levels